# How does SO implement the notification bar?

Tags: discussion, notifications, jquery

I'd like to add a SO-like notification bar to a web page...I'm sure its simple but it's probably been implemented 100 times over by someone. I'm looking for a jQuery plugin. Any links? (or even code!)

Comment: retagged as belongs-on-stackoverflow because this question seems to relate more to programming in general

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a post about someone wondering the exact same question, which I came across it a few days ago on SO.

[Stack Overflow Header Message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605291/header-message-just-like-at-stack-overflow)