# StackOverflow Top Banner

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

Whenever I am on the StackOverflow page, if a new answer shows up on a question I've posted the banner at the top automatically shows informing me of this. What was used to create this effect? I'm wanting to do something similar on a project I am doing as it would be very handy.

Comment: Question is better suited for SO, and has been asked several times
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659199/how-to-show-popup-message-like-in-stackoverflow, not only that, but it has been asked *several* times on MSO already http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8340/how-does-so-implement-the-notification-bar-closed

Comment: I couldn't decide if it was supposed to be here or SO and since it was SO specific I hedged my bets and posted here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welp, as is required in the "I'm building a web site" question:

You should totally use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

StackOverflow uses jQuery for this stuff. While the dev team can answer definitively, it seems that they ping the server to check for an answer every 30 seconds or so (AJAX request), and if that count goes above whatever the original count was, you get a banner displayed using JavaScript.

[SO is built on](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/10370#10370) ASP.NET MVC as its backend, as an FYI.

Comment: I think they probably use Comet actually, not polling, but I don't know.

Comment: They use polling

Comment: Perfect. I figured it was jQuery in some form but unfortunately the extent of my AJAX experience has been via Telerik's RadAJAX libraries. I might be able to make something work between the two though.

Thanks!